# Get exactly data to put on email message?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, automation, google-apps-script-triggers, google-apps-script-add-on

I got a function to email notice like this code below:

```
function approvedby() {
var approvedrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses 1").getRange("E2:E500");
var approved = approvedrange.getValue();

if (approved == "A"){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Responses 1"));
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var dataRange = s.getRange("A2:D500");
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var rowData = data[i];  
var formno = rowData[1]; 
var description = rowData[2]; 
var plant = rowData[3]; 
  
var message = 'Form No: ' + formno + "\n\n" + 'Description: ' + description + "\n\n" + 'Plant: ' + plant + "\n\n";
var subject = "[Approved] Form"
var email = "myemail@hotmail.com";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
}
}
```

Every time I choose "A" on Col E, this message was sent to my email with full data from A2 to D500. I only want to get the data on the same row when I choose "A" on Col E.

1. *Example:* When I choose "A" on Col E2, the message should be sent with the data from A2 to D2 only
2. And when I choose "A" on Col E3, the message should be sent with the data from A3 to D3 only.

How can I do that? I'm a noob at google app script.

Answer (score 0):

We could say that the "problem" is caused by the following lines

`var approvedrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses 1").getRange("E2:E500");`

`var dataRange = s.getRange("A2:D500");`

Those lines are getting values from row to 2 to row 500 while you only want the active row.

You could get the active range by using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`.

If you select the cells or the required row from Column A to Column E you will get the required cells.

I think that it will be easier to make a new script than editing the script included in the question, but this is opt to you.